# Cursor Stooed in a specific text input after typing a text

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React Native App , while im filling the blanks of my text inputs , everything is ok ; However when I handle a specific textinput ( which is described below ) ,where I got enough from typing on it ,I want to leave the textinput but it is stooed and the app runs out !! The problem is actullay is typing on the textinput field  , becauz if once Im handling the textinput whithout typing everything is OK !! plz can i have a solution for this problem

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      evaluate       : "",
  };

}
```

```
validatorPass(text,type){

 const regexPass = /^(\w){3,16}$/
 let faible = " mot de passe faible ";
 let moyen = " mot de passe moyen ";
 let fort = " mot de passe fort "; 

 if (type=='password' && regexPass.test(text)=='true'){

    while (text.length<=4){
      this.setState({evaluate:faible});
    }
   }while(4<text.length<=8){
    this.setState({evaluate:moyen});
   }
   while(8<text.length<=16){
    this.setState({evaluate:fort});
   }

}
```

```
<View style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',marginTop:20,
                              borderColor:'#d9d9d9',
                              borderWidth:1,width:280,marginLeft:40,height:60,zIndex:2}}>
                 <Text style={{width:105,top:-10,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                              paddingLeft:10,paddingRight:10,color:'#808080',
                              marginBottom:-10,marginLeft:20,zIndex:2}}>
                     Mot de passe
                 </Text>

        <Feather name={'lock'} size={24} style={{
                                               position:'absolute',
                                               marginLeft:15,
                                               marginTop:15,
                                               color:'#99ddff'}}/>    
          <View style={{height:40,marginHorizontal:40,marginBottom:50,marginRight:10}}>   
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text)=>this.validatorPass(text,'password')}
                    secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry} 
                    style={{marginHorizontal:30,marginLeft:30,

                            paddingBottom:5}} placeholder='xxxxxxxxxxx'/>

                    {this.state.password   

                    ?

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress ={()=>
                    {this.ChangeState()}}>
                    <Entypo name='eye-with-line' size={20} style={{marginRight:25,left:200,top:-20}}/> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    :
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress ={()=>
                    {this.ChangeState()}}>
                     <Entypo name='eye' size={20} style={{marginRight:25,left:200,top:-20}}/> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>}

          </View>


  </View>
```

Comment: paste code of `this.validatorPass()`

Comment: I edited the response !! I applied a validator to my Password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `validatorPass()` this snippet causing infinite loop, as there is not break condition supplied

```
while (text.length<=4){
    this.setState({evaluate:faible});    
}
```

Moreover, if I understand correctly there must be `if()` statements instead `while()`

```
if (type=='password' && regexPass.test(text)=='true'){

    if(text.length <= 4){
      this.setState({evaluate:faible});
    } else 
    if(text.length <= 8) {
      this.setState({evaluate:moyen});
    } else 
    if(text.length <= 16) {
      this.setState({evaluate:fort});
    }
}
```